# How would I go about installing a bifold barn door?

Tags: doors, closet, barn

I have an opening for a closet that is 59"W 80.5"H

I currently have a cheap bifold pine door with those cheap stamped steel tracks and plastic spring loaded hinges.

I was looking into installing a bifold barn door. However the sizes are listed for tracks and not for the opening. I found [this one](https://www.wayfair.com/home-improvement/pdp/jubest-bi-folding-standard-double-door-barn-door-hardware-kit-jest1075.html).

All the info can be found in specifications or [this PDF](https://secure.img1-ag.wfcdn.com/dm/document/9bbc8d16-d1e2-4c4c-89c5-9c7c6bbdd6ed/61595-3431682-tsq19bk-6.6ft%EF%BC%88170602-2427%EF%BC%89.pdf).

specs 16x4=64 inches

1. This would mean the door would be slightly bigger than opening, by approx. 2 inches either side? Is this standard?
2. The floor is tile and the anchors at the bottom require drilling 4 holes in close proximity to each other. Will it cause the tile to crack over time?
3. Instructions say I need a Mortise Router Head for the bottom mounting hardware but I don't see exactly where to use it? (I don't have that tool)
4. What is this hardware circled in red for?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're worried about the tile cracking, you could cut a chunk out big enough for the pivot pin's plate, and use a filler/spacer.  Of course, that would mean never using a different type of door in the future.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're expected to ask just one question at a time. We're not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

> This would mean the door would be slightly bigger than opening, by approx. 2 inches either side? Is this standard?

Yes. Sliding barn doors are bigger than the opening they close/cover. You can control the amount of overlap by adjusting the widths of the door panels. A 2" overlap on each side of a 59" opening would be 59 + 2 + 2 = 63 inches, ÷ 4 panels = 15 3/4" each door panel. 1" overlap: 59 + 1 + 1 = 61 ÷ 4 panels = 15 1/4" each door panel, etc.

> The floor is tile and the anchors at the bottom require drilling 4
> holes in close proximity to each other. Will it cause the tile to
> crack over time?

It could happen. But tile that is moving is also breaking free of the glue holding the tile down, so a good tile job might not crack. You could also remove a portion of tile at the pivot and replace it with a metal plate for the the pivot hardware to sit on and screw through, or remove a portion for the mounting plate to go on the subfloor itself, to circumvent the tile breakage concern.

> Instructions say I need a Mortise Router Head for the bottom mounting
> hardware but I don't see exactly where to use it? (I dont have that
> tool)

The mortise routing tool is for the red circled hardware, read on.

> What is this hardware circled in red for?

This hardware is also shown on the first page of the PDF, upper right corner, shown backwards from the red circled picture.

If the barn door were going to be only two single sliding doors instead of the four-door bifold pivot arrangement, you would use the red circled hardware on the floor instead of the pivot hardware being instructed in the PDF. You would slot the bottom of the two single doors and mount the red circle hardware so the shorter side goes up into the slots. Then the door would slide instead of pivot.

The PDF does not give instructions on how to mount the hardware as two single sliding doors. So instructions for the use of the red circled hardware are not shown.